How I need to make this request in sequelize, Here is the mysql syntax
I have three tables cours_homework, users and asset-cours.
the cours_homework table contains the foreign keys for the two other tables and I would like to find records with this mysql query in sequelize
select * from cours_homework 
inner join asset_course on cours_homework.assetId = asset_cours.id 
inner join users on cours_home.userId = user.id 
where cours_homework.id = '123ddssdjj54'; 


And what's your question? Where are you stuck at?

you would have your tables defined as sequelize models ex:
CourseHomework, User, and AssetCours.
then you'll execute the query on the CourseHomework Model:
CourseHomework.findOne({
   where: {
    id: 123ddssdjj54,
  },
  include: [ User, AssetCours]
})

in your CourseHomework model, user and assetCours should be defined as Many to one relationship
